# What is yy-mm-dd'D' format?

Tags: python, datetime-format

I got some csv file. Inside file, there is timestamp like this

```
timestamp
2018-08-04D00:00:03.340429000
2018-08-04D00:00:03.911072000
2018-08-04D00:00:04.109119000
2018-08-04D00:00:05.348754000
2018-08-04D00:00:07.569001000
2018-08-04D00:00:08.666946000
2018-08-04D00:00:09.247728000
2018-08-04D00:00:09.247728000
2018-08-04D00:00:09.538240000
2018-08-04D00:00:09.715869000
```

I couldn't convert it to code because of yy-mm-dd **'D'**.
I searched google but I can't find about reference the format..
Is there anyone know about the format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a weird variation of ISO 8601. It can be parsed with a format string:

```
datetime.strptime(d[:-3], "%Y-%m-%dD%H:%M:%S.%f")
```

Comment: Hah yes, definitely. I misread the document of course, and they're reversed for strftime and strptime. Thanks!

Comment: `ValueError: unconverted data remains: 000`

Comment: Since there's no nanoseconds, I've just removed them.

Comment: Maybe mention that the common variation is to use T instead of D (though both are fugly)

Answer (score 0):

The beauty of the `datetime` module is that you can use it to parse almost anything, as long as you know what you are looking for:

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime("2018-08-04D00:00:03.340429000", 
                           "%Y-%m-%dD%H:%M:%S.%f000")
#datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 4, 0, 0, 3, 340429)
```

Note that `'%f'` parses microseconds and demands that there are only six decimal places after the decimal point. The remaining three zeros in my format string tell `strptime` that the last three digits of the string (the nanoseconds) are always zeros.